# Maximum and Minimum distance from query point within bounding box

Tags: computational-geometry, nearest-neighbors

I'm reading an article regarding approximating sums using KD-trees (similar to FMM).

As part of the effort I'm trying to make sense of [this article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f848/6d1be0250a83b447d8ee75043359bcef486f.pdf?_ga=2.159298682.1778656541.1566974675-1838143381.1566818223) , which is cited.

I'm having trouble understanding this part:

> Computing the maximum variation of weights over all points below node
>   ND is easy. We know the location of xquery and we know the bounding
>   hyperrectangle of the current node. A simple algorithm costing
>   O(Number of tree dimensions) can compute the shortest and largest
>   possible distances to any point in the node. From these two values,
>   and the assumption that the weight function is non-increasing, we can
>   compute the minimum and maximum possible weights wmin and wmax of any
>   datapoint below node ND.

The only solution I can think of is to bound the variation (wmax-wmin) from above using the corners of the bounding box, and then computing the distance from the query point to each of the 
 corners is indeed O(d), but there are 2^d corners... But this doesn't seem to be the author's intention. Could anybody point me to what I"m missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the maximum distance it is indeed $O(d)$ where $d$ is the number of dimensions. You only need to test one dimension at a time. If the hyper-rectangle's extent along dimension $i$ is from $H_{i,0}$ to $H_{i,1}$. You test whether $|x_i - H_{i,0}| > |x_i - H_{i,1}|$. If the answer is true, you only need to test half of the remaining corners, only the ones with the $i$'th coordinate equal to $H_{i,0}$, if the answer is false, then the coordinate should be $H_{i,1}$. After testing for $i \in \{0...(d-1)\}$ you get the coordinates of the farthest corner from $x$.

There's no easy way to get an estimate for the lowest possible distance if $x$ is inside the bounding hyper-rectangle, indeed the lowest we can get is simply 0.

If $x_{query}$ is outside the node's bounding hyper-rectangle, you can find the distance from the hyper-rectangle, that would be an estimate for the lowest possible distance. $x_{query}$ may have some of its coordinates inside the extent and some of them outside, you'll need to find a distance from some hyper-plane defined by some of the corners as follows:

Suppose:

$K = \{i \in \{0...(d-1)\} | H_{i,0} < x_i < H_{i,1}\}$, 
$J_0 = \{i \in \{0...(d-1)\}\ \ \  |\ \ \  |H_{i,0} - x_i| > |H_{i,1} - x_i|\text{ and } x \notin K \}$ and 
$J_1 = \{i \in \{0...(d-1)\}\ \ \  |\ \ \  |H_{i,1} - x_i| > |H_{i,0} - x_i|\text{ and } x \notin K  \}$

The distance from that hyper-rectangle will be $\sqrt{\sum_{i\in J_0}(x_i-H_{i,1})^2 + \sum_{i\in J_1}(x_i-H_{i,0})^2}$